# Is there a single-valued function linear in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ that is invertible on $[-\pi, \pi)$ or $[0,2\pi)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

What about $\sin(x/2)$ and $\cos(x/2)$?  My intuition is no, for both, because $f = \sin(x)+\cos(x)$, $f = \sin(x)-\cos(x)$, $f = \sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2)$, and $f = \sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2)$ all don't do the trick, and scaling the terms shouldn't change that.  Can anyone address this more formally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe, linear in $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ means something like $f(x)=a \sin x+b\cos x + c$

Comment: A function of the form $f(x)=F(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ cannot be invertible since $f(2\pi)=f(0)$.

Comment: $\cos(x/2)$ does the trick at $[0,2\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Ah, I missed this before posting, thanks for clearing it up.